# Flyback transformer design process review

Tags: power-electronics, converter, flyback, magnetics, duty-cycle

I was hoping I could get some verification on my flyback design process, and some questions answered.

The document I was following is from Fairchild, [AN4137](https://www.all-electronics.de/wp-content/uploads/migrated/document/167525/46fbe8c82a6.pdf), and the steps below essentially outline its design guide process.

1. **Find Vin_Min**

The flyback I am designing is being fed from a PFC Bus, so, 400 VDC with +/- 2.5% ripple, giving a Vin_min of 390 V.

2. **Determine Dmax and VRO (output voltage reflected to primary side)**

- Using $$VRO = \frac{D_{max}}{1-D_{max}}*Vin_{min}$$
- Plugging that into $$V_{ds} = Vin_{max}+ VRO$$

Change the value of Dmax so that Vds is 65% to 70% of the Vds rating of the MOSFET you are planning to use.

3. **Calculate Primary Inductance**

$$L_{m} = \frac{(Vin_{min}* D_{max})^2}{2 * P_{in} * F_{sw} * K_{rf}}$$

Because this is a **DCM** design, Krf = 1.

Pin = Pout/eff

4. **Calculate Ipr_pk** (primary peak current through Lm)

This allows you to calculate the minimum number of primary turns to achieve a certain Bmax as seen below

5. **Calculate Np_min**

$$Np_{min} = \frac{L_{m} * I_{pk-pk}}{B_{max}*A_{e}}*1E^{+6}$$

Ae is a cross-sectional area of transformer in mm

Bmax is a value you choose, say 0.2 T.

From here calculate the turns ratio and the secondary turns for the regulated winding, and use that winding for calculating other secondary windings.

Something larger 5. **Gap Length Based on Bmax**

$$\mu_{e} = \frac{\mu_{i}}{\mu_{i} *\frac{L_{g}}{L_{e}} + 1}   (Equation 6)$$
$$B_{actual} = \mu_{o}*\mu_{e}*H  (Equation 7)$$

Where, Lg = gap length, Le = MPL (magnetic path length), H = N *I /Le, and $$\mu_{o}= 4 * \pi*10^-7$$

If you substitute mu_e from **equation 6** into **equation 7**, and solve for Lg, you get:

$$Lg = \frac{\mu_{o}* \mu_{i} * N_{p} * I_{pr-pk}}{(B_{m} * L_{e}) - 1)} * (\frac{L_{e}}{\mu_{i}})$$

mu_i is in the initial permeability read off the datasheet.

This equation tells you the gap length required to meet your flux density Bm requirement. Knowing this, you can then use equations 6, and then assume a gap length larger that what you calculated, get a mu_e, and recalculate the inductance using the equation below.

$$L_{mag} = \frac{\mu_{o}* \mu_{e}* N^{2} * A_{e}}{L_{e} + L_{g}}$$

If you choose a gap length where L is now below your spec, increase N by some number, choose an integer value, and go through the process again to get a higher inductance closer to your requirement.

So, does that sound correct?

Another question I have with this process that I'm concerned about is that in the beginning they get you to find VRO based on Dmax (that you choose). But, with a multiple output flyback, how good of an estimation is that VRO, since, at this point the equation I referenced in **step 2** doesn't account for any secondary voltages. How does that equation represent the reflected output voltages? Or am I missing something and their procedure is fine?

Comment: I would start with circuit design parameters such as ~Vin, ~Vout and switching frequency. calculate turns ratio and necessary Webers from there, *then* infer the necessary core size.

Comment: Check your calculated results using a simulator if you want strong confirmation that you have done the process correctly. Also, can you use Latex mark-up language. Does "mew" = \$\mu\$?

Comment: @Andyaka I didn't know how to use that Latex language but I just re-wrote the equations in it, should be much more readable now. I ran the flyback in PSIM assuming all the power running through the regulated winding, given the steady-state biasing parameters and the output voltage and peak current through Lm correlate quite well with the calculated values. The thing I haven't used with PSIM is the magnetic circuits. Do you have some intuition, or able to address, my last question about VRO?

Comment: @RogerDodger good job on the latex and note that \$\cdot\$ or \$\times\$ = `\$\cdot\$ or \$\times\$`. Good job on the simulation too but, I think you need to model the inductors as not 100% coupled as this produces an unwanted flyback spike on the primary that can damage the transistor. In other words you might need a "spike catcher". TBH I didn't understand what the VRO bit was about.

Comment: @Andyaka thanks. Yea, I usually do an ideal analysis, make sure the DC operating parameters are working, then add the non-idealities. I usually start leakage somewhere between 5% to 10% of the reference inductance (this one being magnetizing inductance). Here's another website that is doing a QR flyback design (https://electronicsbeliever.com/quasi-resonant-flyback-step-by-step-design-guide/), and they are using Vref as what I call VRO. Could you take a look and see how they are ensuring Vref is relevant and actually is being designed for?

Comment: @Andyaka Or, do you think it's a waste of time? It didn't seem to effect my results, when I look at Vds across my FET the VRO that is supposedly designed for is not being shown within the simulation, it's quite off...

Comment: OK, I understand what \$V_{RO}\$ is now. From your question, \$V_{RO}\$ is the naturally (and expected) reflected voltage on the primary when the MOSFET deactivates (ignoring leakage flyback). It can be calculated from any of the multiple outputs just by considering transformer action. Is there something that is confusing you about it?

Comment: Where my confusion lies is entirely around the fact that when people use this style of designing a flyback transformer, this equation or step, is one of the first. But, how does that equation take into account how many windings there are and there voltages? I think the answer to that lies in the fact we know the output power and therefore the energy being transferred back to the output  (neglecting leakage and other XFMR losses). But, I still don't understand how my first equation takes any of that into account.

Comment: @Andyaka are you able to address my comment RE around my confusion?

Comment: I'm not understanding your confusion. I read it twice but nothing clicked.

Comment: @Andyaka Hmmm. okay, lets look at your comment of "It can be calculated from any of the multiple outputs just by considering transformer action". Let's say you have a 5V winding, 15V, and a 50V. Your comment implies that the reflected voltage will be same somewhat the same regardless of which winding you choose. To me that is confusing, because I would expect the 50V winding to have a higher reflected voltage back to the primary than the 5V winding.  What does the "transformer action" have to do with this? Does that clarify my confusion?

Comment: The 5 volt output might have (say) 5 secondary turns and, the 50 volt output might have 50 secondary turns so, whichever secondary winding you analyse, will result in the same flyback voltage on the primary.

Comment: @Andyaka okay figured, just wanted to make sure it wasn't something else. thanks.

Comment: Do you want me to leave a formal answer that you can accept @RogerDodger

Comment: @Andyaka sure thing